# Sine curve arc length

Tags: differential-equations, differential-geometry

```
 Clear[A, Lam]
DSolve[Len'[x] == Sqrt[((2*Pi*A)/Lam)^2*
      (-Sin[(2*Pi*x)/Lam]^2) - ((2*Pi*A)/Lam)^2 + 1], Len, x]
ArcLen[x_, A_, Lam_] = Sqrt[(Lam/(2*Pi))^2 - A^2]*
    EllipticE[(2*Pi*x)/Lam,(4*A^2*Pi^2)/(Lam^2 - 4*A^2*Pi^2)]; 
A = 1.; Lam = 8; 
Plot[A*Sin[(2*Pi*x)/Lam], {x, 0, Lam}]
Plot[ArcLen[x, A, Lam], {x, 0, Lam}]
ArcLen[Lam/2, A, Lam]
```

I am trying to find arclength of a Sinewave using Elliptic Integral of second kind as defined by Mathematica. But cannot have a plot for full domain or Evaluate. Please help.

Comment: See here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395

Comment: Even your user defined function must use `[]` not `()`.

Comment: I cut and pasted from Traditional, instead of Input Form. Either it should not work or work fully, right?

Comment: @Narasimham no "Output from TraditionalForm cannot necessarily be given as unique and unambiguous input to the Wolfram Language."

Comment: Thanks, did not know, now changed.

Comment: Your ArcLen function becomes increasingly imaginary which `Plot` cannot handle.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica 10.4 has `ArcLength`. You can you code for yourself:

```
i = ArcLength[Sin[x], {x, 0, s}];
v = {t, Sin[t]};
a = Integrate[Sqrt[D[v, t].D[v, t]], {t, 0, s}, 
   Assumptions -> {s \[Element] Reals}];
TraditionalForm[
 Grid[{{HoldForm[Integrate[Sqrt[D[v, t].D[v, t]], {t, 0, s}]], a},

   {HoldForm[ArcLength[Sin[x], {x, 0, s}]], i}}, Frame -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of Sin[x] I want to include the more general A Sin [ 2 Pi x/Lam] to result in  a closed form/ analytical expression involving second kind Elliptic integrals of the sine curve arc length at any fraction of Lam, the wavelength.

Comment: @Narasimham apologies. Perhaps you can adapt code. I have had 2 glasses of wine and am going to sleep...good luck:)

Comment: @ubpdeqn Tried out your code and works numerically fine.  For the general solution, me too allowing some time for the sub-conscious .. Good night!